How to set LADSPA plugin in asound.conf in Linux?
I am working on embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10), and the system needs to setup ladspa plugin to deal with audio.
My setting of asound.conf is as follows, which defines a PCM device named mono_ladspa_pcm and the chain of ladspa plugins to play audio in mono channel.
pcm.mono_ladspa_pcm {
    type ladspa               # Use ladspa plugin
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,4"          # input device
    }
    channels 1                # mono channel

    playback_plugins {        # Playback plugin definition.
        0 {                   # 1st plugin
            label "lpf"       # plugin name/label
            input {
                bindings {
                    0 0       # connect input channel to plugin's input
                }
            }
            output {
                bindings {
                    0 0       # connect plugin's output to output channel
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

With above settings, there is NO sound played back.
I am sure of the settings of plugin's path, the label or ID is correct and the hardware is good.
Updated with ladspa filter plugin.
Here is another asound.conf with ladspa low-pass-filter.
pcm.my_lpf {
    type ladspa                  # LADSPA
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,4"             # input device
    }
    channels 1                   # mono-channel
    path  "/usr/lib/ladspa"

    playback_plugins {           # plugin definition
        0 {
            label "lpf"          # plugin lable: lpf
             input {
                bindings {
                    0  1         # input channel to lpf input
                }
                controls {
                    4  5000
                }
            }
            output {
                bindings {
                    0 2          # lpf output to output channel.
                }
            }
            controls {
                    4  5000
            }
        }
    }
}

I spent lots of time doing testing and debugging, but still failed to make them work.
